# TFS 2013: Customize Git build template error: custom template not found

Tags: tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2013 Update 5 and a Git repository. I need to customize the default Git build template (GitTemplate.12.xaml).

I created a new branch and pushed the modified build template. Next, I created a new build definition to test the custom template, specified the new branch under the "Source settings". Selected the new template under the Process tab but when I run the build, it is not able to find the template. It throws the below error:

> TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build
>   definition \MobilePayments\CheckinToDevelop-notes:  Exception Message:
>   Git repository for path
>   vstfs:///Git/VersionedItem///feature//BuildTemplate/GitTemplate.12_custom.xaml
>   was not found. (type FileNotFoundException)

Any clues why it would not be able to find the template while running the build?

Comment: Can you access the build template `GitTemplate.12_custom.xaml` from the Git branch? make sure it is available in the git team project.

Also, please open the build definition file, the check and make sure that the `GitTemplate.12_custom.xaml`  file is available in the `Build process` file dropdown list.

Comment: Yes, it is available. It is there in the drop down and I get the option to download and view the file. If I click on the view link, it opens the browser and navigates to the file correctly. I even tried moving it to the master branch but no luck.

Comment: Does the agent service account have the permission to access the specific branch? Just try another agent to check if that works. Also try to create a new team project then commit and push to a new repo to check if that works.

Comment: That’s a good point, I did not think about that, I will check and give the agent service account the required permissions. Thanks!

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Thanks for pointing in the right direction. It was indeed a permissions issue. The build agent service account did have access to the branch however it was the build controller service account that also needed access to the branch as the controller is the first point where it downloads the template and then searches for an available agent to execute the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an permissions issue.

So just make sure the `build agent service account` and `the build controller service account` have the correct permission to access to the branch.

See @DevOpsy's clarification in comments:

> The build agent service account did have access to the branch however
>   it was the build controller service account that also needed access to
>   the branch as the controller is the first point where it downloads the
>   template and then searches for an available agent to execute the
>   build.